# Return value of Textpaint.breakText

Tags: android

According to Andorid api reference,Textpaint.breakText (String text, boolean measureForwards, float maxWidth, float[] measuredWidth) returns The number of chars that were measured. Will always be <= abs(end - start). Now i want to break "Traffic"(which has 7 chars) to test its return value:

```
int cnt = mTextPaint.breakText("Traffic", true, 10000, outMeasuredWidth)
```

To my opinion, it should return 7,but actually it returns 6. why 6 other than 7? Thanks.

Comment: try `mTextPaint.setSubpixelText(true);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is because the "fi" in the word Traffic is considered as one unit or glyph. This is the case when your font uses [ligatures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographic_ligature).

Contrary to what is mentioned on the API reference for Paint.breakText(), the method counts glyphs and not characters.

I would suggest either using a font without ligatures or using measureText() to determine number of characters.

There is a bug filed but the fix has not yet been made.

References:

[Paint.breakText() counts glyphs, not characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20341196/paint-breaktext-counts-glyphs-not-characters)

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=39365